# Issue creating a folder then moving files into it within the same script

Tags: linux, shell

I'm having problems moving files into a folder after I create it in a shell script.

My script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "Processing\033[36m" $1 "\033[0mwith the German script";
if [ ! -d ${1%.dat} ]; then
   echo -e "making directory\033[33m" ${1%.dat} "\033[0msince it didn't exist..."; 
   mkdir ${1%.dat};
fi
```

...processing occurs here... (irrelevant to issue)

```
if [ -d ${1%.dat} ]; then
   mv useragents_$1 /${1%.dat}/useragents_$1;
   mv summary_$1 /${1%.dat}/summary_$1;
   more /${1%.dat}/useragents_$1;
else
   echo -e "\033[31mERROR: cannot move files to folder.\033[0m";
fi
```

As you can see I create the folder if it doesn't exist in the top section and then if it exists I move the files into that folder in the bottom section, the problem is that it doesn't create the folder in time to move the files in (I'm assuming) so when it reaches the lower code, I only get the ERROR.

I tried using, sleep 5, but it only slows down the script and has no effect on the ERROR.

I would really appreciate some advice.

Errors below:

```
mv: cannot move `useragents_100_stns2_stns6.dat' to `/100_stns2_stns6/useragents_100_stns2_stns6.dat': No such file or directory
mv: cannot move `summary_100_stns2_stns6.dat' to `/100_stns2_stns6/summary_100_stns2_stns6.dat': No such file or directory
/100_stns2_stns6/useragents_100_stns2_stns6.dat: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Are you trying to create `${1%.dat}` in your root folder? Because you are trying to move in a folder located at root

Comment: yes, it should be created where the script is executed, it actually does create the folder it just doesn't move the files into it.

Comment: Just remove the `/` before `mv useragents_$1 /${1%.dat}/useragents_$1;`and `mv summary_$1 /${1%.dat}/summary_$1;`

Comment: Oh, my goodness, time to hide my head in shame. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Pass 1

Your check:

```
if [ ! -d ${1%.dat} ]; then
```

should be:

```
if [ -d ${1%.dat} ]; then
```

You created the directory; if it is a directory, move stuff into it.

*Typo in question*

#### Pass 2

You create:

```
mkdir ${1%.dat}
```

You try to move files:

```
mv useragents_$1 /${1%.dat}/useragents_$1;
```

Note the leading slash in the move compared to the create.  Make those consistent.

Comment: haha, well typos definitely don't help but unfortunately I made that while typing it into Stack Overflow. I'll fix that above.

Comment: New diagnosis under Pass 2 heading.  Diagnosed without seeing the comments to the main question — but the same diagnosis as in the comments to the main question.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure of this part ? It uses a root directory.

```
/${1%.dat}/summary_$1;
```

You probably want to do this instead:

```
${1%.dat}/summary_$1;
```

It allows you to move the file into the directory IN your current directory.